# Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null for to do list

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make to do list but keep getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null. I moved my script file to the bottom of the body tag and still get the error. I also tried putting it at the top and using defer and that didn't work. I tried using If(todoBTN) { todoBTN.addEventListener('click', addTodo) and it got rid of the error but when I ran a console.log test I didnt't see it get logged.

```
 const todoBTN = document.querySelector('addtodo-btn')
 const inputTodo = document.querySelector('todo-input')
 const todoList = document.querySelector('todo-list')
 const form = document.querySelector('form')

 todoBTN.addEventListener('click', addTodo)



 form.addEventListener('submit' , event => {
 event.preventDefault();
 })

 function addTodo() {

// Create Div
const divTodo = document.createElement('div')
divTodo.classList.add('itemsDiv')
// Create To Do Item
const todoItem = document.createElement('li')
todoItem.innerText = inputTodo.value;
divTodo.appendChild(todoItem)

todoList.appendChild(divTodo)
}


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>To do List</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Slab&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.14.0/css/all.css" 
 integrity="sha384-HzLeBuhoNPvSl5KYnjx0BT+WB0QEEqLprO+NBkkk5gbc67FTaL7XIGa2w1L0Xbgc" 
 crossorigin="anonymous">
 </head>
 <body>
 <h2>To Do List</h2>
 <form class="form">
    <input type="text" class="todo-input">
    <button class="addtodo-btn" type="submit"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>
 </form>

<div class="todo-container">
    <ul class="todo-list"></ul>
</div>

<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: `querySelector('.addtodo-btn');` ----> `querySelector('.addtodo-btn');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `class selector` use `.` with in `queryselector`.See usage [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

```
const todoBTN = document.querySelector('.addtodo-btn') // use . here for class
```

Same for others as well

```
 const inputTodo = document.querySelector('.todo-input')
 const todoList = document.querySelector('.todo-list')
 const form = document.querySelector('.form')
```

Comment: wow thank you i can't belive it was that simple , i still have a lot to learn thank you again

Comment: `.form` is not necessary. `form` is also fine

Comment: he has a class with form so :)

Answer (score 0):

You forget to add (.) in front of class name.